# Android styles.xml window title

Tags: android, xml

In styles.xml, in my user's style I can't set window title size (height).

[image]

It's always the same.

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">20dip</item>
```

and

```
<style name="my_menu" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomMenuTitle</item>
    ...
<style/>

<style name="CustomMenuTitle" >
    <item name="android:layout_height">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">12dip</item>
<style/>
```

*** EDIT ***

```
in manifest.xml:

<activity android:name=".DlgSubmenuZnajdz"
          android:screenOrientation="sensor"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:theme="@style/my_menu">
</activity>
```

not working.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: See in * EDIT * in question, manifest fragment.

Comment: my_style working properly without this one item: size of the title. Bkg, text size & color I may change without problems.

Comment: Try my edit, see if it works.

Comment: The same. Cant change window title size.

Comment: Ensure you are not using Action Bar instead of regular title bar

Answer (score 0):

If you set a custom style, you also have to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Something like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/my_menu">
```

You can also apply your custom theme to an specific `Activity`. Like the example below.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.Activity" android:theme="@style/my_menu">
```

---

**Edit:** Try the following xml:

```
<style name="my_menu" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:layout_height">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomMenuTitle</item>
    ...
<style/>

<style name="CustomMenuTitle" >
    <!-- customize other stuff here, like the example below -->
    <item name="android:textSize">20dip</item>
<style/>
```

Comment: This is no answer. My custom theme working with any options without windows title size set.

Comment: Wait, what? Could you please clarify?